# Read data from pre-existing Excel file in Java

Tags: java, excel, readfile, filenotfoundexception

I'm having trouble reading data from a pre-existing Excel file.

An example of a fileName is "Donors By Last Name - Thu Dec 15 08/20/40 PST 2016.xls"

This is what my method looks like:

```
public void addDonorsFF() throws IOException
{
    JTextField a = new JTextField(20);
    Object[] message = {"Enter File Name:", a, "\nIt is best to directly copy paste the file name, including .xls \nYou cannot import Shipping files."};
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Select File", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
    {
        String fileName = (String)a.getText();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xls file
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++)
        {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for(int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++)
            {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

                //Some code that uses the data in the cell and puts it in a "donor" object;
            }
        }
        workbook.close();


    }
}
```

I know the file exists for certain, but when I run the program I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Donors By
>   Last Name - Thu Dec 15 08/20/40 PST 2016.xls (No such file or
>   directory)
>
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>
> at Directory.addDonorsFF(Directory.java:115)
>
> at Driver.main(Driver.java:24)

I hope there's something simple, this is just going over my head because I'm a beginner. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: where is the file located?

Comment: My desktop @RamPrakash

Comment: your file's name contains space?

Comment: yes. it probably shouldn't, the reason is bc I'm concatenating the date to the file name using Date() to avoid overwriting files in my writeToFile method and there's spaces in that when it's converted to a String. Should I remove them? @andolsizied

Comment: concat  `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of Date().tostring()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your file is on your desktop, but you didn't fully qualify that in your file name to open.  This should be something like "C:\users\myname\desktop\Donors..."  (if Windows).

The way you entered the file name, it will only look in the current folder where you are running your application for the file.